# Why is this for loop code as fast as apply()?

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, apply

**EDITED to provide re-producible results**

It wasn't clear initially, but I need the results to take into account NAs in the raw data (df)

#### #

I initially wrote my code with for loops to get the proof of concept working, but now I need to speed things up.  It runs in ~2-3 minutes with the for loops, but when I re-wrote it using apply(), it wasn't any faster. I thought apply() should be the vectorized solution and therefore faster, but maybe my whole premise is incorrect?  (I am not new to R, but computational speed is not usually an issue for me.)

I am working with 1000+ cases and ~100 variables and need to perform 5000+ simulations with the data (turning on and off different conditions).

**Starting definitions & sample data:**

```
cases = 1000
variables = 100
simulations = 5000

df <- as.data.frame(array(rnorm(cases * variables, 0, 5), dim=c(cases, variables)))

montecarlo <- matrix(rbinom(simulations * variables, 1, 20/variables), simulations, variables)
montecarlo[montecarlo==0] <- NA

calc <- array(,dim=c(cases, variables, simulations))
interim <- array(,dim=c(cases, variables, simulations))
results <- array(,dim=c(variables, simulations))

for (j in 1:simulations) {
  calc[,,j] <- exp(t(t(df) * as.numeric(montecarlo[j,])))
}
```

**For loop version:**

```
for (j in 1:simulations) {
  interim[,,j] <- t(apply(calc[,,j], 1, function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))) # re-share
  results[,j] <- apply(interim[,,j], 2, sum) # aggregates results
}
```

**Apply() version:**

```
interim <- apply(calc, c(1,3), function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)) # re-share
results <- as.data.frame(t(apply(interim, c(1,3), sum))) # aggregates results
```

I am open to any suggestions to speed things up and/or a reason why the apply() version is not any faster.  Thank you!

Comment: There could be numerous suggestions for speeding up your code. But without a reproducible example it's almost impossible to help. Can you make an example which we can all use by copy & pasting it into our sessions? And a clear description of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: The answer provided below is 100% fully sufficient. R's for loops **were** inherintly slow quite a few years back, but were updated and are now faster. One should think of `*apply` functions are sugar-coated for loops. No matter how you put it, the apply functions need to iterate. Sadly it is still knowledge spread around, that loops are "slow".  Check out (Why loops are slow in R)[https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/], where Florian Privé explains why many new R-users still believe this is the case.

Comment: I've added a reproducible example for the record.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mikko Marttila noted, the `apply()` family does not guarantee faster code. Using `sweep` and `aperm()`, the code below is about 3x faster for a 1,000 x 100 x 70 array (i.e., only 7 million elements).

```
results4 <- colSums(sweep(calc, c(1,3), colSums(aperm(calc, c(2,1,3)), na.rm = T), FUN = '/'), na.rm = T)
```

Or, for slightly less performance but is more similar to what you originally had:

```
interim3 <- sweep(calc, c(1,3), apply(calc, 3, rowSums, na.rm = T), FUN = '/')
results3 <- apply(interim3, c(2,3), sum, na.rm = T)
```

**Performance**:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      for_loop 510.9131 514.9030 537.0344 518.2491 524.5709 705.4087    10
      apply_OP 446.0352 458.4940 491.6710 500.1995 523.1843 533.9654    10
 sweep_rowSums 225.5855 233.2632 252.6149 240.7245 284.1517 292.3476    10
   sweep_aperm 136.2519 140.8912 163.7498 154.6984 191.5337 217.8015    10
```

**Data**

```
cases = 1000
variables = 100
simulations = 70

set.seed(123)
calc <- array(sample(cases *variables * simulations),dim=c(cases, variables, simulations))

interim <- array(,dim=c(cases, variables, simulations))
results <- array(,dim=c(variables, simulations))

# Original Loop
for (j in seq_len(simulations)) {
  interim[,,j] <- t(apply(calc[,,j], 1, function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))) # re-share
  results[,j] <- apply(interim[,,j], 2, sum) # aggregates results
}

# original apply

interim2 <- apply(calc, c(1,3), function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)) # re-share
results2 <- apply(interim2, c(1,3), sum) # aggregates results

# using sweep

interim3 <- sweep(calc, c(1,3), apply(calc, 3, rowSums, na.rm = T), FUN = '/')
results3 <- apply(interim3, c(2,3), sum, na.rm = T)

#using sweep and aperm
# interim4 <- sweep(calc, c(1,3), colSums(aperm(calc, c(2,1,3)), na.rm = T), FUN = '/')
results4 <- colSums(sweep(calc, c(1,3), colSums(aperm(calc, c(2,1,3)), na.rm = T), FUN = '/'), na.rm = T)

all.equal(results4, results3, results2, results)



library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  for_loop = {
    for (j in seq_len(simulations)) {
      interim[,,j] <- t(apply(calc[,,j], 1, function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))) # re-share
      results[,j] <- apply(interim[,,j], 2, sum) # aggregates results
    }
  }
  ,
  apply_OP = {
    interim2 <- apply(calc, c(1,3), function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)) # re-share
    results2 <- apply(interim2, c(1,3), sum) # aggregates results
  }
  ,
  sweep_rowSums = {
    interim3 <- sweep(calc, c(1,3), apply(calc, 3, rowSums, na.rm = T), FUN = '/')
    results3 <- apply(interim3, c(2,3), sum, na.rm = T)
  }
  ,
  sweep_aperm = {
    results4 <- colSums(sweep(calc, c(1,3), colSums(aperm(calc, c(2,1,3)), na.rm = T), FUN = '/'), na.rm = T)
  }
  , times = 10
)
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks for your answer!  I will use your new code, although I am wondering if I can speed everything up by making "interim" a temp 2 dimensional matrix and overwriting it each time "results" gets calculated.  I don't actually need "interim", it is only temporary (and takes up a lot of memory).

Comment: @datajoel - see edit, I removed the ```temp``` and it improved performance by around 15%.

Comment: Update: Combining all the learning from here plus some other efficiencies (using colSums / rowSums instead of apply) I was able to speed everything up by a factor of 4-5.  Thank you again!

Comment: You should add an edit at the end of your question with the end result. Also, it is good practice to also upvote an answer in addition to accepting it as the solution.

Comment: I upvoted you already too, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show up.  I will edit in my latest changes when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: for-loops aren’t inherently slow. If you’re preallocating output (i.e. not growing a vector, causing multiple copies), they’re pretty much comparable to `*apply()` functions in speed. The overhead in iterating comes from repeatedly calling R functions from C code; and the advantage of using functionals is simply [clarity](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions). Here’s an example with a for-loop wrapped in a function:

```r
foo <- function(x, f, ...) {
  out <- vector("list", length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    out[[i]] <- f(x[[i]], ...)
  }
  out
}

x <- replicate(10000, rnorm(30), simplify = FALSE)
bench::mark(foo(x, mean), lapply(x, mean))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 foo(x, mean)      36.9ms   38.4ms      26.1   157.3KB     52.3
#> 2 lapply(x, mean)   42.6ms   44.9ms      22.3    78.2KB    100.
```

The way to get speed improvements in these cases is to move all of the calculations into compiled code.

That said, there may well be other optimizations for your specific problem. You might want to provide a reproducible example, and ask a new question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) about performance improvements.

<sup>Created on 2019-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the info!  Very helpful to know for loops aren't necessarily slower.